# Scala: Implementation of flatMap using foldRight

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am having trouble understanding the solution to the functional programming exercise:

> Implement `flatMap` using only `foldRight`, `Nil` and `::` (cons).

The solution is as follows:

```
def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = 
   xs.foldRight(List[B]())((outCurr, outAcc) =>
   f(outCurr).foldRight(outAcc)((inCurr, inAcc) => inCurr :: inAcc))
```

I have tried to factor out anonymous functions into function definitions to rewrite the solution to no luck. I cannot understand what is happening or think of a way to break it down so it's less complicated. So, any help or explanation regarding the solution would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, just ignore the constraints and think about the `flatMap` function in this case. You have a `List[A]` and a function `f: A => List[B]`. Normally, if you just do a `map` on the list and apply the `f` function, you'll get back a `List[List[B]]`, right? So to get a `List[B]`, what would you do? You would `foldRight` on the `List[List[B]]` to get back a `List[B]` by just appending all elements in the `List[List[B]]`. So the code will look somewhat like this:

```
def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
    val tmp = xs.map(f) // List[List[B]]
    tmp.foldRight(List[B]())((outCurr, outAcc) => outCurr ++ outAcc)
}
```

To verify what we have so far, running the code in REPL and verify the result against built-in `flatMap` method:

```
scala> def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
 |     val tmp = xs.map(f) // List[List[B]]
 |     tmp.foldRight(List[B]())((outCurr, outAcc) => outCurr ++ outAcc)
 | }
flatMap: [A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B])List[B]

scala> flatMap(List(1, 2, 3))(i => List(i, 2*i, 3*i))
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9)

scala> List(1,2,3).flatMap(i => List(i, 2*i, 3*i))
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9)
```

OK, so now, look at our constraints, we are not allowed to use `map` here. But we don't really need to, because the `map` here is just for iterating through the list `xs`. We can then use `foldRight` for this same purpose. So let's rewrite the `map` part using `foldRight`:

```
def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
    val tmp = xs.foldRight(List[List[B]]())((curr, acc) => f(curr) :: acc) // List[List[B]]
    tmp.foldRight(List[B]())((outCurr, outAcc) => outCurr ++ outAcc)
}
```

OK, let's verify the new code:

```
scala> def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
     |         val tmp = xs.foldRight(List[List[B]]())((curr, acc) => f(curr) :: acc) // List[List[B]]
     |         tmp.foldRight(List[B]())((outCurr, outAcc) => outCurr ++ outAcc)
     |     }
flatMap: [A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B])List[B]

scala> flatMap(List(1, 2, 3))(i => List(i, 2*i, 3*i))
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9)
```

OK, so far so good. So let's optimize the code a bit, which is instead of having two `foldRight` in sequential, we'll combine them into just one `foldRight`. That shouldn't be too hard:

```
def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
    xs.foldRight(List[B]()) { (curr, acc) => // Note: acc is List[B]
        val tmp2 = f(curr) // List[B]
        tmp2 ++ acc
    }
}
```

Verify again:

```
scala> def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
     |     xs.foldRight(List[B]()) { (curr, acc) => // Note: acc is List[B]
     |         val tmp2 = f(curr) // List[B]
     |         tmp2 ++ acc
     |     }
     | }
flatMap: [A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B])List[B]

scala> flatMap(List(1, 2, 3))(i => List(i, 2*i, 3*i))
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9)
```

OK, so let's look at our constraints, it looks like we can't use `++` operation. Well, `++` is just a way to append the two `List[B]` together, so we can certainly achieve the same thing using `foldRight` method, like this:

```
def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
    xs.foldRight(List[B]()) { (curr, acc) => // Note: acc is List[B]
        val tmp2 = f(curr) // List[B]
        tmp2.foldRight(acc)((inCurr, inAcc) => inCurr :: inAcc)
    }
}
```

And then, we can combine them all into one line by:

```
def flatMap[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = 
   xs.foldRight(List[B]())((curr, acc) =>
   f(curr).foldRight(acc)((inCurr, inAcc) => inCurr :: inAcc))
```

Isn't it the given answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is easier to understand with a simple example:
Suppose we have a `val xs = List[Int](1,2,3)` and a function `f: Int => List[Int], f(x) = List(x,x) (lambda x => List(x,x))`
Appling f to each element of xs `List(f(1),f(2), f(3))` will result in `List(List(1,1),List(2,2),List(3,3))` so we need to flatten out this List[List[Int]]. The final result should be List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3). Given Cons (::) the constructor of nonempty List, this should be `Cons(1, Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(3, Nil))))))`. Observe `foldRight` operation in the result, which applies the constructor Cons (::) to the result of f applied to each element of the list xs. So a first implementation of flatMap would be

```
def flatMap[A,B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = xs match {
  case Cons(head, tail) => foldRight(f(head), Nil)((a,b) => Cons(a,b))
}
```

In this form, `flatMap(List(1,2,3))` will return List(1,1) or `Cons(1,1,Nil)` (by substitution). So we need to continue down with a recursive call to `flatMap` on the tail (reducing the problem by 1 from 3(elements) to 2(elements)) and adding the base case for the case of an empty List as Nil (Nil is the "zero" element for Cons operation)

```
def flatMap[A,B](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case Cons(head, tail) => foldRight(f(head), flatMap(tail)(f))((a,b) => Cons(a,b))
}
```

which is the final implementation.